# Storing a variable number of files' download statistics in mysql database

Tags: mysql, statistics

I have a number of files on my website that are private and pushed through php. I keep track of the downloads using a mysql database. Currently I just use a column for each file and insert a new row for every day, which is fine because I don't have many files.

However, I am going to be starting to add and remove files fairly often, and the number of files will be getting very large. As I see it I have two options:

The first is to add and remove columns for each file as they are added and removed. This would quickly lead to the table having very many columns. I am self-taught so I'm not sure, but I think that's probably a very bad thing. Adding and removing columns once there are a lot of rows sounds like a very expensive operation.

I could also create a new database with a generic 'fileID' feild, and then can add a new row every day for each file, but this would lead to a lot of rows. Also, it would be a lot of row insert operations to create tracking for the next day.

Which would be better? Or is there a third solution that I'm missing? Should I be using something other than mysql? I want something that can be queried so I can display the stats as graphs on the site.

Thank you very much for your help, and for taking the time to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I could also create a new database with a generic 'fileID' feild, and then can add a new row every day for each file, but this would lead to a lot of rows.

Yes, this is what you need to do — but you mean "a new *table*", not "a new *database*".

Basically you'll want a `file` table, which might look like this:

```
 id | name      | created_date | [other fields ...]
----+-----------+--------------+--------------------
  1 | foo.txt   | 2012-01-26   | ...
  2 | bar.txt   | 2012-01-27   | ...
```

and your `downloads_by_day` table will refer to it:

```
 id | file_id | `date`     | download_count
----+---------+------------+----------------
  1 |       1 | 2012-01-27 |             17
  2 |       2 | 2012-01-27 |             23
  3 |       1 | 2012-01-28 |              6
  4 |       2 | 2012-01-28 |            195
```

Comment: Whoops, didn't know enter would submit these. Anyway, if I can't find any other solution I will use that one. Thanks for your answer. I'm just new and unconfident about how efficient my designs are.

Comment: @JeremyMiller: Don't say "if I can't find any other solution". Trust me, this is almost certainly what you want to do. (I've expanded my answer a bit, by the way, to show how it might look.)

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot for the extra effort! I appreaciate it. I will go with this then.

Comment: @JeremyMiller This is definitely what you want to do. Your current design is not [Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_form) Which is why you are experiencing your current problems. Change your design to the above, it's the ideal way to design this db.